# Jenkins Mstest plugin strips out the double quotes in the command line while trying to run multiple test categories

Tags: jenkins, mstest, jenkins-plugins

Trying to get multiple test categories run via Jenkins mstest plugin command line gives a error

**Command line Auguments** :/testsettings:Test\Tests\Local.testsettings /category:"!FAIL&!LIVE"
gives
 **Console output** :cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"  /resultsfile:Test\Tests\TestResults\Endpoints\Tests.trx /testsettings:Test\Tests\Local.testsettings /category:!FAIL&!LIVE /testcontainer:Test\Tests\Tests\bin\Endpoints\Tests.dll && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
Error:'!LIVE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

**Manual run via cmd** : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /resultsfile:Test\Tests\TestResults\Endpoints\Tests.trx /testsettings:Test\Tests\Local.testsettings /category:!FAIL&!LIVE /testcontainer:Test\Tests\Tests\bin\Endpoints\Tests.dll

This works when run via cmd but not with jenkins plugin

How do I get jenkins plugin not to strip out the quotes ? Or is there any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug related with https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13412